# Sundials installed but not running in python with assimulo

Tags: sundials, assimulo

Cheerio,

I am trying to use Assimulo 2.9. on a Mac OS X. For that I downloaded and installed sundials via cmake by creating a builddir to the Download file and ../Downloads/sundials-2.7.0 running

```
        $cmake ../Downloads/sundials-2.7.0
        $make 
        $make install
```

This should install everything in /usr/local. 
It gives me no error warning when doing this. But when I am trying to use assimulo in python, following error message occurs:

```
        from .sundials import IDA, CVode
        ImportError: No module named sundials
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you look at the installation log (for Assimulo) it should print whether or not it finds Sundials during the installation. Have you looked there?

Comment: After lots of muddling, I resorted to homebrew to install assimulo. The difference I saw was that the sundials library had been included as a .so file. Now it works pretty well, although it says that it cannot find glimda. I guess that it is the same issue: the glimda.py and glimda.pyc files are included, but no shared object library so assimulo cannot call it and read out the included variables. I put the question to the people at jmodelica, but so far no answer.

Comment: The glimda solver requires that blas and lapack are specified during the installation, see the installations instructions on the assimulo homepage. If this was not done during the installation, glimda will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to install everything through homebrew and get the missing sundials.so file. It seems that the current assimulo-2.9 distribution on pypi does not provide this shared object library and therefore triggers this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, in Anaconda(Ubuntu 18.04). I installed pyfmi first, and then installed the dependencies (assimulo, sundials) according to the error message. After everything was installed, the pyfmi was not working by running an fmu example.

But i uninstalled all the related software. Then i reinstalled everything with certain order. I found the order of installation matters, which are: sundials --> assimulo --> pyfmi.
Everything is good now.